# Only run macro once

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

My excel-sheet uses a relatively complex VBA-function that loads data via a http-request. Since my sheet has around 3K rows, recalculating this for every single row is extremely time consuming. In Detail, I'm calculating the driving distance between two given coordinates. Since this never changes, there is no need for me to recalculate at any time.

Now when I for instance sort the table or insert some rows, ALL of the rows in the excel sheet are recalculated, which takes around 2 hours to complete.

Is there a way to run a macro only once? Eg. calling the function in the cell and then replacing the cell value with the function return value, like this:

```
//Cell-Content before macro is executed:
=CALCULATEDISTANCE(POINT A; POINT B)

//Cell-Content after macro is executed:
33 miles
```

But what I want to achieve is not just to display the distance in miles (that already works). I want the cells TEXT to be "33 miles" instead of "=CALCULATEDISTANCE(...)". As mentioned, I do not need to call the function more than once per row.

Comment: Instead of using the function as UDF, write an extra sub routine that loops over all rows and calls the calculation routine for those rows where the distance was not yet calculated. This Sub can write the result into the distance cell in any form you want. You just need to decide how to call that routine, eg via Button, or even via scheduler. Usually you could use the Change-Event, but as the code is so slow, that's maybe not the best idea.

Comment: If I correctly understood your question, you can simple copy all the range where no need of any modification and then paste it as value. The formulas will be gone and some new rows to be calculated should be fast enough...

Comment: You could add a test at the beginning of your macro to check if the value in the cell is 0 then get the distance if not exit out

Comment: @FunThomas has given the route I'd go down.  On top of that I'd give the cell a custom format of `0 "miles"` - it can still be used in calculations then as the cell will only hold the numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
CurrentVal = CCur(Application.Caller.Text)
If IsEmpty(CurrentVal) Or CurrentVal = 0 Then
  ' do your distance calc here
End If
```